# Ajax called html will not fit inside div properly

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I click on a div I have an ajax call return some html and it fits the height fine but it is overflowing the width. This ajaxed html is responsive so it should adjust to fit the div's width just fine but it isn't for whatever reason. Thanks.

Javascript:

```
//Jquery ajax call
$( "#loadOne" ).click(function() {
    $('.boxSix, .boxFix').css('height','auto');
    $('.boxSix').load('../aboutMe.html #aboutMeBody');
});
```

HTML:

```
<a id="loadOne">
    <div class="boxSix col-sm-6 clearfix" ><!-- box 6-->
        <h3>
            <img class="icons" src="images/aboutMeIcon.svg" >
            <p>About me.</p>
        </h3>                   
    </div><!-- end of box 6-->
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.boxSix{
    background-color: $colorFour;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-width: $width;
    border-color: $borderColor;
    border-style: $style;
    height: 250px;  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your html too?

Comment: Can you show the css or create a fiddle of the returned html and css

Comment: I posted the basic html and css of it but if a fiddle would be better I will do that.

Comment: will you try `$('.boxSix, .boxFix').css('overflow','visible');`  ?

Comment: If I take away the overflow it just spills out of the div container. The div is outlined with black borders.